# Como posso controlar o tempo que um dado foi inserido no banco de dados - sqlLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Preciso de fazer o controle do tempo que um dados é inserido no banco de dados, para fazer determinadas ações em função do tempo.

Pensei em fazer a diferença entre a hora atual do sistema e a hora da inserção, mas com isso a um certo problema, caso o usuário altere a hora do seu dispositivo o programa já não funcionará corretamente.

Como eu posso fazer o controle das horas, mesmo o usuário alterando a hora do seu dispositivo eu consiga saber quantas as horas foi inserido um dados.

**Eu vi que os estados do whatsapp funcionam do mesmo jeito.**

Comment: Pegando o horário da internet?Assim mesmo que o usuário mude o horário do dispositivo, não afetará a aplicação

Comment: Acho que é uma boa sugestão, como fazer se o dispositivo não estiver conectado a Internet?